# IOS Core Data or Caching for Offline User Experience

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, caching, core-data

I am fairly new to IOS and looking for a way to improve user experience especially when Network is bad or there's no network at all. The app uses a Rails server as a back-end.

For example, users can send messages to each other, and I would like to be able to display the 10 most recent conversations of the user even if he is offline, so that he can still check his last messages.

What is the best way to accomplish that kind of features? Is it with Core Data or some caching techniques?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is definitely a good approach for caching, but is generally built for enormous amounts of data. It's extremely quick but rather hard to use and meant for much more complex situation than saving cache.
I don't know your app so I cant really tell what you should use, but there are other options you might want to look at like `NSUserDefaults` and `NSCache` which are extremely easy to use but considered slower. And of course you can find plenty of third-party options on Github.
Good luck!